# How to get the SignatureValue with php?

Tags: php, hash, rsa, sha1, private-key

It is said that to obtain the SignatureValue the following must be done:

- 1. Hash using SHA-1
- 2. Encrypt with RSA private key
- 3. Base64 encode the result

Using this javascript code [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jybaro/xmvov1c3/), of the following structure:

```
<ds:SignedInfo xmlns:ds="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#" xmlns:etsi="http://uri.etsi.org/01903/v1.3.2#" Id="Signature-SignedInfo284666">
<ds:CanonicalizationMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/TR/2001/REC-xml-c14n-20010315"></ds:CanonicalizationMethod>
<ds:SignatureMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#rsa-sha1"></ds:SignatureMethod>
<ds:Reference Id="SignedPropertiesID687634" Type="http://uri.etsi.org/01903#SignedProperties" URI="#Signature680220-SignedProperties883886">
<ds:DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#sha1"></ds:DigestMethod>
<ds:DigestValue>E+ZfetOb53KRrXMOx27aZUg7B5o=</ds:DigestValue>
</ds:Reference>
<ds:Reference URI="#Certificate280377">
<ds:DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#sha1"></ds:DigestMethod>
<ds:DigestValue>X7MPKnMutOGD1ge+DhS6DBpsAk4=</ds:DigestValue>
</ds:Reference>
<ds:Reference Id="Reference-ID-863720" URI="#comprobante">
<ds:Transforms>
<ds:Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#enveloped-signature"></ds:Transform>
</ds:Transforms>
<ds:DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#sha1"></ds:DigestMethod>
<ds:DigestValue>wSfLV4gKPewaYvBC35hJVYA/oVs=</ds:DigestValue>
</ds:Reference>
</ds:SignedInfo>
```

The following result is obtained:

```
NW0PePGqFoDXSKTG5IwUuK89KIPj5aJuwykuml182fnedUKYg/8BfVbKbtPAJmHWv3Wb765Qf0A3
kyk6TG5r0RmKdt6KWjoOHrq1050QJtVqDzz34IpipfDX4D/qk4AE/zrr57BOMbbxxgbqjm3VvcbG
4tjSI2eiyxUu47KhlIfB6a5SKoWgfZrVmKQLiw+QB51S225EhxPVI6fimWtRcEaJlh4NormxGjcg
0Crf6MPjsAgk7pVW5RrliFTQdrmJHfwZl8tKpTtFiADeu2YsU3CG9okwU277ccHtCWlGs5ZKvUSm
mlDk5pdlFIaaw6PpAISk48PN926bH0EifTEVxQ==
```

Now I try to get the same result with PHP, as follows:

```
$privateKey = '-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----
MIIEvwIBADANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQEFAASCBKkwggSlAgEAAoIBAQCC2nH/FRU+za+w nKYrkToXxvYm7O2dxQK8Dtwen3VjnRNVFTgOOWI6bcHKp1NhGXbUehzdqG6A/B/f hg37ipWofhIezfGWaq8gxMSTsBAr8RwkSDXMgO8mQHCWJ3rbtGNbdYTFncWxGTiq eaNBnZpEJH6bPqzLnuhOqha5au7FfP0tUX8kFVNKq93K/fiyuWBeFYxHcqOR6xME +Gl/b3aIFaV0gEhYwzKfoQBxZjaBWxvA1H9qbjP1rkhhSKcqU8Ko8ZdzdnlI8T09 wO/v06R3AtB9j6Y4+hCeMbQZq6D8rOJ3Nd9VOO2tUXlHGksZ2BMIWPsgXOYG70dk b+k6Sgy5AgMBAAECggEAKImiDUMrzMQN7Knq9M5N7/XMZiy6REk3WqlD2hzOUijk R1SGhCmU28MK6UxDEW7BGHwoGydF7KGvAiFWjZnWWVeNJ4vnjxDH5l/vAk3mBKby b+8K86rx66jE+E+MySmuKjRTCKGjEAVfP7jlMbuwgfHIYzHceExnbY9V8OVGyVlI 1etLOoIw24L+LH11BhNoJWSHOb0DFIhDoPC5fevJQblLfPmPbKVhE9GZ1Vg4ezGc +vuYgFABNDYIh8ifK678oQF03ayLCDfmdpqYKcg2p+wcbFWpNgzGp/NByvzKb0Ki nHkLf6liRc+2ZeDZOsso4k3LprTdeq0ow19dYnYcHQKBgQCvCwoBDzNDaf7kMJg8 PGL+NRDWVR+eWL1TtN9dLxCWuFr6gijTle0UUGg5Dm8dn7QqwaIJAbDP4NYGVTaW IptDtUuDjbj6mIiC/5jkfHYyIXppGQJTe0AME20o1N9Da/MbY6u5Cl97rMIMW2fI yLaTmgbnYW4sS5JcdkNa3h1FgwKBgQC/X148u1QuZSW/a1H1dfDtyCxIUh/RUWVt MCRqe3OzuVqY6ZPpPXyCiSOMuvZrIx3hMLfIoieaOL1Q3XDPmS0C8U1pvNgagE6E eMZadCeWkhJKkCPkh5vsgA0cpapqtAeqNoisuGkGSAC9W8Z+L4kfVQS4vZOsfFKZ F2deDqlMEwKBgQCF+lsT6ICCTvULz64WHNpgXFmg09K5ro5rLXvxpP57fmwUZd+9 43ltHQZI9aVS9VQ/janqXuLomdz3R+3aCG7y6ib8cFNva6TBL8XkzObjBADfxIal QycIly3sHNMulcej5SwhG7FtxhNYxfWwFwC4BSLXoxliyg0ivFpdiLi65QKBgQCD ZPJqFmCdHjuFqyTxuJG8YRTubtyDtjRCfKx0I+D0BA6NMMqqeNn1Mj2jUXcBZnIM fIujCJrSS6TIUdIz50K9Y3o4YD2sLG48jEP8NQY9XnuKkF7keKt4/Q6DncddTdB5 cMn0dQU/F87SNKIbX33xckk0oo0y/4Uisav6K2zX2wKBgQCYEAEXMyfrKst0q8Gv lqUtCIV/9Cv/GiANeWdlqubzxvte7aIt5wwaEdJe+6cCl3teXzSHiKZ/zxHjRxvg axnexRIYGrsw7CldR3odxX8TDQExkXmd1NSOSDMX9mFyLgK0iTdx/5x/i8wYRlba 7tAM0w0wuONKwLXt9cQ7bjwoJg==
-----END PRIVATE KEY-----';
$SignedInfo = '<ds:SignedInfo xmlns:ds="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#" xmlns:etsi="http://uri.etsi.org/01903/v1.3.2#" Id="Signature-SignedInfo284666">
<ds:CanonicalizationMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/TR/2001/REC-xml-c14n-20010315"></ds:CanonicalizationMethod>
<ds:SignatureMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#rsa-sha1"></ds:SignatureMethod>
<ds:Reference Id="SignedPropertiesID687634" Type="http://uri.etsi.org/01903#SignedProperties" URI="#Signature680220-SignedProperties883886">
<ds:DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#sha1"></ds:DigestMethod>
<ds:DigestValue>E+ZfetOb53KRrXMOx27aZUg7B5o=</ds:DigestValue>
</ds:Reference>
<ds:Reference URI="#Certificate280377">
<ds:DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#sha1"></ds:DigestMethod>
<ds:DigestValue>X7MPKnMutOGD1ge+DhS6DBpsAk4=</ds:DigestValue>
</ds:Reference>
<ds:Reference Id="Reference-ID-863720" URI="#comprobante">
<ds:Transforms>
<ds:Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#enveloped-signature"></ds:Transform>
</ds:Transforms>
<ds:DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#sha1"></ds:DigestMethod>
<ds:DigestValue>wSfLV4gKPewaYvBC35hJVYA/oVs=</ds:DigestValue>
</ds:Reference>
</ds:SignedInfo>';

$sha1 = sha1($SignedInfo);
openssl_sign($sha1, $SignatureValue, $privateKey, 'sha1WithRSAEncryption');
$resultSignature = base64_encode($SignatureValue);
echo $resultSignature;
```

But I get the following output:

```
Dfx4ck6bix1jL4f97hNjTikzMVEhsoJPMjd1SOSH8/AKVhAIhzejxQuHE8QT5DJqAY5hg18SLqam
p8OekAgu2CXzKPY5pVYVICP5hARGbxELAwsmpiVRSGSwnBxBw1hkrQHF63rfGCnHDRO9p/6t5du1
PIqZ+Ng9ibvJYPkRcEyRE/tRV1NaiaHUPX6vuNg2WJFj11ncyOWFKSMlJD4MT08zHovTPjiCBs87
+MuZsfL7fiEuynfurEByk7EcSWOhgVl/2A4u1InOPZjd7+XdDCo2uaftrrXW6hUzXfEkKOBxdIRp
SEKaaQ2xvvWaiISX1S0PufE6ODJP5UcKNKrJ8A==
```

What am I doing wrong? Any change I need to add in PHP to get the same result:

```
NW0PePGqFoDXSKTG5IwUuK89KIPj5aJuwykuml182fnedUKYg/8BfVbKbtPAJmHWv3Wb765Qf0A3
kyk6TG5r0RmKdt6KWjoOHrq1050QJtVqDzz34IpipfDX4D/qk4AE/zrr57BOMbbxxgbqjm3VvcbG
4tjSI2eiyxUu47KhlIfB6a5SKoWgfZrVmKQLiw+QB51S225EhxPVI6fimWtRcEaJlh4NormxGjcg
0Crf6MPjsAgk7pVW5RrliFTQdrmJHfwZl8tKpTtFiADeu2YsU3CG9okwU277ccHtCWlGs5ZKvUSm
mlDk5pdlFIaaw6PpAISk48PN926bH0EifTEVxQ==
```

Comment: Your JS version uses `\n` for line breaks, make sure that its the same in your PHP version - and not `\r\n` or just `\r` perhaps. Especially when you are uploading the file via FTP somewhere, you would have to pay close attention to wether you upload it as "ASCII" or "Binary".

Comment: (To eliminate the line breaks as a possible reason, you could also encode some short, static text like `foobar1234` first - and see if that gives you the same result in both versions.)

Comment: @CBroe Interesting, the issue of space would not be a problem, otherwise I understand very well, the certificate, the private or public key must be converted to "Binary" or "ASCII" and, how it would be used, I hope to find something that guides me, thanks for commenting.

Comment: The PHP code does not provide the posted signature Dfx4... Is the data consistent, i.e. was the signature generated with this key and plaintext?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`openssl_sign()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.openssl-sign.php) hashes *implicitly*, i.e. the unhashed data must be passed:

```php
...
openssl_sign($SignedInfo, $SignatureValue, $privateKey, 'sha1WithRSAEncryption');
...
```

With this change, the PHP code returns the desired signature `NW0P...EVxQ==`.

Comment: Run the fixed code online here: https://paiza.io/projects/708b7_qa56RYqj_6z0wKaA

Comment: You have to make some configuration in PHP, because in the online compiler the desired hash is output but when executing it on my server another one is output

Comment: @OneL - There is nothing to configure regarding `openssl_sign()`, so it must be general PHP settings, possibly line breaks (see CBroe's comment), encoding, etc. If your environment uses `\r\n` and not `\n` as in the JavaScript code, try `$SignedInfo = str_replace("\r\n", "\n", $SignedInfo);` *before* the `openssl_sign()` call. If this doesn't help post the output of `print(bin2hex($SignedInfo));` for further analysis as well as the signature you generated.

Comment: I will try the commented, but I had already tried to eliminate spaces and line breaks and even canonical with C14N here the test: https://paiza.io/projects/4JwU85aGivxJZg_oJkJEOA?language=php

Comment: @OneL - You must not change the formatting, otherwise a different signature will be created. You may only replace the `\r\n` (if there are any) with `\n`. Your `trimRemove()` cannot actually work. Try the fix I suggested and if that doesn't work please post the data I asked for.

Comment: Thanks friend it worked, could you help me with this last question:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73789434/how-to-get-the-same-javascript-hash-in-php, please